# Define Filemanager rooth path via url in iframe

Tags: php, iframe

I'm using [filemanager](https://github.com/alexantr/filemanager) that i think it's perfect for my project. The only problem is that i should limit the rooth path of it via php script. I have a directory structure like this:

```
1 (directory)
2 (directory)
3 (directory)
....
filemanager.php
```

I want that via script i'll be able to limit the root dir to just one of the numeric directory without seeing all the others. I don't want to copy the filemanager in each directory and manually edit inside it the rooth_path variable, so i've decided to make an external embed.php file like this:

```
<?php
$root_path='Z:/www/archives/'.$_GET['dir'].'/';
define('FM_EMBED', true);
require 'filemanager.php';
?>
```

And then call the embed file from an iframe like this:

```
<iframe src="embed.php?dir=<?php echo $id;?>"></iframe>
```

The problem is that since filemanager rewrites the `GET` parameter of the request, the `dir` param is lost even before the first step. What other solution could i use to achieve my goal without rewriting the filemanager code itself?

Comment: The solution i finally used is to copy the `embed.php` file with the directory written in. I found no other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it was easiet than expected. I just used the php `SESSION` to store the parameter the first time that the embed script is called. So the `embed.php` now look like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['dir']))
    $_SESSION['dir']=$_GET['dir'];
$root_path='Z:/www/archives/'.$_SESSION['dir'].'/';
define('FM_EMBED', true);
require 'filemanager.php';
?>
```

Comment: I found out that this solution it is not working. If you open multiple tabs with different path on them, the session remembers the last dir opened, so all the tabs will operate on the same directory which will often be wrong.